# Aftermath of the battle between Kassad and the Shrike

Tags: hyperion-cantos

How did this battle was a major influence on history/future of humankind, if The Shrike is described to continue existing during the events described later, which happened "before" it was sent back in time (encountering Sol and Rachel, battle with Brawne, etc.)?